# How do I make UIScrollView remember the position after a Segue is performed?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uiscrollview, storyboard

I am using a UIScrollView with an extended content size and have placed many objects within it. It scrolls like a map. Clicking on a button within the UIScrollView will perform a Segue and takes the user to another Scene (another UIView embedded within a UINavigationController). Within the second Scene, clicking on another button will perform another Segue to bring back to the original Scene (the UIScrollView which scrolls like a map).

Everything works fine, EXCEPT that when it returns to the original Scene, it goes back to the default position. HOW do I make it remember the original position? Imagine that it is a map, and by return to it, it should be showing where it left off and users don't need to re-scroll to the previous place. How can I do that?

I am using Storyboard on iOS 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform a segue, that will push the "new" scene on to your navigation stack. If that scene is subsequently "popped" (which would be the default behavior of the UINavigationController's back button in the new scene), the user should be returned to the original view at the desired content offset automatically. If this is not happening, you may accidentally be pushing a new instance of the original view controller. You should not be performing an additional segue, rather you should be popping the top view controller off of the navigation stack. That said, you can use this rather heavy-handed method for making sure the content offset remains regardless:

Before you perform your segue, set the property to the value of your scrollView's contentOffset property, e.g.:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue
{
    [self setScrollViewOffset:self.scrollView.contentOffset];
}
```

When this view controller prepares to make another appearance, set it's scrollview's contentOffset:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear
{
  [[self scrollView] setContentOffset:self.scrollViewContentOffset animated:NO];
}
```

Comment: - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [dashboardScrollView setContentOffset:dashboardContentOffset animated:NO];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    dashboardContentOffset = dashboardScrollView.contentOffset;
}

Answer (score 4):

To go back to the previous view, you should not use Segue. Simply use the following line of code:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The position in the original view should stay as it was. By using Segue to push to another view (no matter to the previous view), you actually create another instance of view controller like this:

```
VC A -> VC B -> VC A
```

You can test it by adding another button on VC A and B, and use the above code to verify if your VCs being popped up in the sequence. Your VC A's scroll position is not remembered because a new instance of VC A is created. The first VC A would ever be reachable if you use segue.

Answer (score 1):

First make sure

```
scrollView.delegate=self;
```

second in delegate method,remember scrollView.contentOffset.x as class variable

```
-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    self.offsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
}
```

Third,back from navigation

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    CGRect frame=scrollView.frame;
    frame.origin.x=self.offsetX;
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:NO];
}
```

Or change offsetY if scroll vertically

Answer (score 0):

To let UIScrollView remember content position between view controller transitions UIScrollView.contentSize should be set correctly before any transition.